# Simple file copying, different behavior on different file types

Tags: c, pdf, jpeg

I was trying out some of the file manipulation techniques in C, and so I wrote a simple program that takes a file as input and copies it into an empty file. I opened the file-to-read with fopen() in 'binary' and 'read' modes, read all bytes one by one using fgetc() and wrote them to the file I wanted written that was opened in 'write' and 'binary' modes. When the copying operation finishes(EOF), I called fclose() on both files and terminated the program.

Here's the problem: everything works perfectly fine for text files, but when I try to copy a file in a different format like a pdf or a jpeg I get segmentation fault. Since the code is really short and simple, I suspect that this problem is caused by my lack of understanding about reading and writing those file formats in C rather than a bug in the code.

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome, and if you suspect that I might have done something wrong with the code, I can post it as well.

Edit: Ok, so I probably messed up the code and here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXCHAR 10000000

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( argc != 3)
    {
        printf( "usage: fileexer1 <read_pathname> <write_pathname>");
        exit( 1);
    }

    FILE* file_read;
    FILE* file_write;

    int nextChar;
    char readBuffer[MAXCHAR];
    int valid = 0;

    // These hold the path addresses to the files to be read and written
    char* read_file_path = argv[1];
    char* write_file_path = argv[2];

    // The file to be read is opened in 'read' and 'binary' modes
    file_read = fopen( read_file_path, "rb");
    if( !file_read)
    {
        perror( "File cannot be opened for reading");
        exit( 1);
    }

    // The file to be written into is opened in 'write' and 'binary' modes
    file_write = fopen( write_file_path, "wb");
    if( !file_write)
    {
        perror( "File cannot be opened for writing");
        exit( 1);
    }

    nextChar = fgetc( file_read);
    while( nextChar != EOF)
    {
        readBuffer[valid] = (char) nextChar;
        valid++;
        nextChar = fgetc( file_read);
    }

    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < valid; i++)
    {
        fputc( readBuffer[i], file_write);
    }

    fclose( file_read);
    fclose( file_write);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Certainly, C knows nothing about the format of files, so you must have a bug in your code. Please, post.

Comment: yes I know that it's not efficient to read one char at a time, I am just experimenting but some of the files I tried were smaller than 10MiB, do you think there might be another error in the code rather than the redundancies?

Comment: @john27: actually, using getc/putc isn't all that inefficient -- behind the scenes, the library will do buffering for you, so you read larger chunks (e.g., 4KiB) at a time anyway.

Comment: Not sure it's at the root of your current problem, but you might want to consider what happens if you try to copy a file that is larger than `MAXCHAR`....

Comment: Well I just discarded the whole idea of using a buffer as Jerry Coffin said, and it worked. Although I got the segmentation fault not in larger files than 10MiB but on some files about 7MiB, I guess the buffer was the reason behind the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to read and write character by character anyway, there's little point in allocating a huge buffer to hold the data. Ignoring error checking:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

   FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
   FILE *outfile = fopen(argv[2], "wb");

   int ch;

   while (EOF != (ch = getc(infile)))
      putc(ch, outfile);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to wager a guess there's something wrong with your code as there's nothing fancy going on with writing any binary type file. Binary is binary. Here's some code which copies an image called 1.jpg to 2.jpg.

```
int main (){
    FILE *readf, *writef;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    unsigned long len;
    int i=0;

    //Open file
    readf = fopen("1.jpg", "rb");
    writef = fopen("2.jpg","wb");

    //you should check if readf & writef were opened successfully here...

    //Get file length
    fseek(readf, 0, SEEK_END);
    len=ftell(readf);
    fseek(readf, 0, SEEK_SET);

    //Allocate memory
    buffer=(char *)malloc(len);

    //check that buffer got memory allocated here... 

    fread(buffer,fileLen,sizeof(unsigned char),readf);
    fwrite(buffer,fileLen,sizeof(unsigned char),writef);

    //cleanup
    fclose(readf);
    fclose(writef);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to read one character at a time, you don't need to save 10 million of them in a buffer on the stack.  And your code won't handle files bigger than 10 million bytes gracefully.

Simply use `fputc(nextChar)` in the input loop before the `fgetc()` call, and eliminate the `readBuffer` variable and the output loop.  You can still count the valid characters if you want, but there's no need.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( argc != 3)
    {
        printf( "usage: fileexer1 <read_pathname> <write_pathname>");
        exit( 1);
    }

    FILE* file_read;
    FILE* file_write;

    int nextChar;

    // These hold the path addresses to the files to be read and written
    char* read_file_path = argv[1];
    char* write_file_path = argv[2];

    // The file to be read is opened in 'read' and 'binary' modes
    file_read = fopen( read_file_path, "rb");
    if( !file_read)
    {
        perror( "File cannot be opened for reading");
        exit( 1);
    }

    // The file to be written into is opened in 'write' and 'binary' modes
    file_write = fopen( write_file_path, "wb");
    if( !file_write)
    {
        perror( "File cannot be opened for writing");
        exit( 1);
    }

    while ((nextChar = fgetc(file_read)) != EOF)
        fputc(nextChar, file_write);

    fclose( file_read);
    fclose( file_write);

   return 0;
}
```

Note that some systems have problems with 10 MiB stacks.  If you want to be more efficient, consider using a 64 KiB buffer and then use `fread()` and `fwrite()` to read and write chunks of data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( argc != 3)
    {
        printf( "usage: fileexer1 <read_pathname> <write_pathname>");
        exit( 1);
    }

    FILE *file_read;
    FILE *file_write;
    char buffer[64*1024];
    size_t nbytes;

    // The file to be read is opened in 'read' and 'binary' modes
    file_read = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!file_read)
    {
        perror("File cannot be opened for reading");
        exit(1);
    }

    // The file to be written into is opened in 'write' and 'binary' modes
    file_write = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (!file_write)
    {
        perror("File cannot be opened for writing");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((nbytes = fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), sizeof(char), file_read)) != EOF)
    {
        if (fwrite(buffer, nbytes, sizeof(char), file_write) != nbytes)
        {
            perror("Failed to write to file");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    fclose(file_read);
    fclose(file_write);

   return 0;
}
```

Using `perror()` restricts the usefulness of your messages; it is better to use `fprintf(stderr, ...)`, but I've not fixed that for you.